# How to get the number of element in a root json elment

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the number of elements in each node of a Json.
For example in this case:

```
{
  "tickets": {
    "use": "Valida",
    "useagain": "Valida di nuovo",
    "usetitle": "Convalida biglietto",
    "price": "Prezzo"
  },
  "fares": {
    "nofarestopurchase": "Non è possibile acquistare biglietti per la tratta indicata",
    "purchasedcongratulations": "Congratulazioni",
    "farepurchased": "Hai acquistato il tuo biglietto. Lo puoi trovare nella sezione",
    "mytickets": "I miei biglietti",
    "fareguestcard": "Hai ottenuto il tuo biglietto. Lo puoi trovare nella sezione"
  },
  "quantity": {
    "title": "Seleziona il numero di persone:"
  }
}
```

> Ticket contains 4 voices, it contains 4 fares and quantity 1.

How do I get in a dynamic way the nodes and the number of elements inside them in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` on an object to get an array of its keys; then, use the array's `length` property to find the number of keys in the array.

So, if your JSON structure is `yourJSON`, you can do:

```
var ticketsNum  = Object.keys(yourJSON.tickets).length; // 4
var faresNum    = Object.keys(yourJSON.fares).length; // 4
var quantityNum = Object.keys(yourJSON.quantity).length; // 1
```

For nested data, like you have here, you could easily write a function that will count the key/value pairs of each of the "top-level" keys:

```
function countKeys (obj) {
    var count = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        count[key] = Object.keys(obj[key]).length;
    });
    return count;
}

var nums = countKeys(yourJSON);
// nums = { tickets: 4, fares: 4, quantity: 1 }
```

Comment: The problem with this way is that I do not know how it will be structured the json file

Comment: @LeonardoMidolo With this `countKeys` function, you don't need to know what the key names will be. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Now that I have the object, you know how I can access the number of components, for example "ticket"?
What I need is to have the root element and the associated number of components.

Comment: `Object.keys(yourObj).length`, if I understand want you want. With the example object you gave, this would be 3.

Comment: Suppose you have a json like this, how do I get the number of components ticket ? 
status: {
  "title": "Il tuo stato",
  "tickets": {
   "title": "Biglietto"
  }
 },

Comment: Whatever object you want to count the keys for, just pass the object to `Object.keys(obj).length`. So, in this case, `Object.keys(obj.tickets).length`.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do to make it dynamically ? without knowing you have the "ticket "item ?

Comment: Well, you could write a function that take the object and the key name: `function countKey(obj, key) { return Object.keys(obj[key]).length; }`

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, my problem is how to verify the existence of the element "ticket" because with Object.keys (JSON) I just get the "primary" attributes without (in this case) "ticket"

Comment: Well, to see if some `obj` has a property `prop`, you can just do `if (obj.prop) { }`. But maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: How can it works with root  elements in  the second third and so on level. Is there a way to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
Object.keys( obj ).forEach( function(key){
  console.log( "It has " + Object.keys(obj[key]).length + " " + key );
});
```

where `obj` is the object variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Modern Browsers have an `Objects.keys` that can help you, generraly it used like this:

```
Object.keys(jsonArray).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var ticket =  {
     "tickets": 
     {
        "use": "Valida",
        "useagain": "Valida di nuovo",
        "usetitle": "Convalida biglietto",
        "price": "Prezzo"
     },
     "fares": 
     {
        "nofarestopurchase": "Non è possibile acquistare biglietti per la tratta indicata",
        "purchasedcongratulations": "Congratulazioni",
        "farepurchased": "Hai acquistato il tuo biglietto. Lo puoi trovare nella sezione",
        "mytickets": "I miei biglietti",
        "fareguestcard": "Hai ottenuto il tuo biglietto. Lo puoi trovare nella sezione"
     },
     "quantity": 
     {
        "title": "Seleziona il numero di persone:"
     }
}

var result = {};

for(prop in ticket) { 
   if(ticket.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      result[prop] = { length: Object.keys(ticket[prop]).length };
   }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // {"tickets":{"length":4},"fares":{"length":5},"quantity":{"length":1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try recursion. Yes this is little slow, but will be scalable.

For demonstration purpose, I have updated json to show nested objects.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dzrwuwxo/).

```js
var data = {
  "tickets": {
    "use": "Valida",
    "useagain": "Valida di nuovo",
    "usetitle": "Convalida biglietto",
    "price": "Prezzo"
  },
  "fares": {
    "nofarestopurchase": "Non è possibile acquistare biglietti per la tratta indicata",
    "purchasedcongratulations": "Congratulazioni",
    "farepurchased": "Hai acquistato il tuo biglietto. Lo puoi trovare nella sezione",
    "mytickets": "I miei biglietti",
    "fareguestcard": "Hai ottenuto il tuo biglietto. Lo puoi trovare nella sezione"
  },
  "quantity": {
    "title": "Seleziona il numero di persone:"
  },
  "test": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  "test2": {
    "foo": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    }
  }
}

function getCount(obj, result) {
  if (typeof(obj) === "object" || Array.isArray(obj)) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(_key) {
      return (function(key) {
        if (typeof(obj[key]) === "object" || Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          result = result || {};
          result[key] = {};
          result[key].count = Object.keys(obj[key]).length;
          Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(k) {
            getCount(obj[key], result[key]);
          });
        }
      })(_key)
    });
  }
}

var r = {};
getCount(data, r);
console.log(r);
```