# How to obtain all root element in a json using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

suppose to have a json like this:

```
 errors: {
 "cannot.fetch.credit":"Ops... non riesco a leggere il credito.",
 "not.enough.credit.to.buy":"Non hai abbastanza credito per comprare questo biglietto."
},
status: {
    title: "Il tuo stato",
    message: "Hai effettuato l'accesso come",
    credit: "Credito",
    notickets: "Nessun biglietto prenotato",
    scanqrbus: "Inquadra il QR code all'interno del bus",
    tickets: {
        title: "Biglietto"
    }
},
```

I know, this is not a valid json but let's assume that it is.

To obtain elmenti first level use the root json.keys () function ..
But that's not good because I do not get (in case there are) the elements of the second third and so on level.
Is there a way to be able to do this?

What I want to achieve in the end is an object that contains the root element and then (errors, status, tickets) With the respective size `prova= { errors: 2, status: 5, tickets: 1 }`

Comment: Please give us your result you want :)

Comment: @LeonardoMidolo You want to access `cannot.fetch.credit` in `errors`?

Comment: What I want to achieve in the end is an object that contains the root element and then (errors, status, tickets) With the respective size   //prova= { errors: 2, status: 5, tickets: 1 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var json = {
  errors: {
   "cannot.fetch.credit":"Ops... non riesco a leggere il credito.",
   "not.enough.credit.to.buy":"Non hai abbastanza credito per comprare questo biglietto."
  },
  status: {
    title: "Il tuo stato",
    message: "Hai effettuato l'accesso come",
    credit: "Credito",
    notickets: "Nessun biglietto prenotato",
    scanqrbus: "Inquadra il QR code all'interno del bus",
    tickets: {
      title: "Biglietto"
    }
  }
};

// Get a errors property
console.log(json.errors['cannot.fetch.credit']); // Ops... non riesco a leggere il credito.

// Get a status property
console.log(json.status.title); // Il tuo stato

// Get a tickets property
console.log(json.status.tickets.title); // Biglietto
```

Comment: [obtain root element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162194/how-to-get-the-number-of-element-in-a-root-json-elment)    This method worked great, the problem is that it stops at the first level.

Answer (score 0):

To access properties that contains special values you will need [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
var obj = {
  "special.values.here": 123,
  "foo bar baz": 456
};
console.log(obj["special.values.here"]); // 123
console.log(obj["foo bar baz"]); // 456
```

This also enables accessing properties with variables:

```
var key = "foo bar baz";
console.log(obj["foo bar baz"]); // 456
```